# Detect the bottom of a list in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I appreciate this question might be asked a lot and I've seen/tried many answers but I can't find a solution that doesn't involve conventional arrays. I have a data set with the following structure and example data:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let status : String
    let total, startIndex, pageSize, currentPage, pages: Int
    let results: [Result]
}
struct Result: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id, sectionName: String
    let fields: Fields
}
struct Fields: Codable {
    let trailText, bodyText, headline, thumbnail: String
}
```

Example data:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "total": 50,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "pages": 5,
    "results": [
        "id": "random_id1",
        "sectionName": "test",
        "fields": [
            "headline": "test",
            "trailText": "test",
            "bodyText": "test",
            "thumbnail": "test",
        ],
        "id": "random_id3",
        "sectionName": "test",
        "fields": [
            "headline": "test",
            "trailText": "test",
            "bodyText": "test",
            "thumbnail": "test",
        ],
    ]
}
```

I currently loop through results in my list to display information to the user. Once the user has reached the end of the data, I want to call an API that loads more data in (infinite scroll). I cannot get it to work where either only the first set is loaded or all the data is loaded at once.

My current progress loads data only when the last row is selected, but I want to load the data as soon as the last row appears.

```
class Newsfeed: ObservableObject {

    @Published var data = [Result]()

    func loadData(pageNum: pageNumber) {
        // Do API request here and populate data with result
    }
}
```

My View has the following structure:

```
@ObservableObject var newsfeed = Newsfeed()
@State var page: Int = 1 

init() {
    newsfeed.loadData(pageNum: page)
}
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(data) { item in
            Text(item.field.headline)
            Text(item.field.thumbnail)
            Text(item.field.trailText)
            Text(item.field.bodyText)
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        if (self.data.last != nil) {
            newsfeed.loadData(pageNum: page + 1)
            self.page += 1
         }
    }
}
```

I have tried the indices method to detect what row it is currently on and then compares it with the data count, but indices don't work.

How can I detect that the bottom has been reached and automatically load the data in? My theory is that data initially has x elements. Once I reach the last row, I am updating data to have x + x, but the view is unchanged and only updates once it goes to another view and returns.

Comment: Check this tutorial, I think you can get the idea for your structure
https://www.vadimbulavin.com/infinite-list-scroll-swiftui-combine/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, I guess I was just calling the `onAppear` too late and should have been called inside the foreach. I had to change the dataModel to make Result and Fields both equatable and then you can do the following:

```
List {
    ForEach(data) { item in
        Text(item.field.headline)
        Text(item.field.thumbnail)
        Text(item.field.trailText)
        Text(item.field.bodyText)
            
        .onAppear(){
            if (self.data.last == item){
                newsfeed.loadData(pageNum: page + 1)
                self.page =+ 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your data model conforms to Identifiable you can also check if the `id` of the last item in the list matches the `id` of the item in the `ForEach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

we can do like this, add a footer as ProgressView(), when it appear to loadData

```
List {
      
    Section(footer: ProgressView()
    .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden).onAppear(){
                        
    if (self.data.last == item){
           newsfeed.loadData(pageNum: page + 1)
           self.page =+ 1
     }                  
    }){
            ForEach(data) { item in
            Text(item.field.headline)
            Text(item.field.thumbnail)
            Text(item.field.trailText)
            Text(item.field.bodyText)
         }
       }
}
```